# construct a tree out of list of strings

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I have 400 lists that look like that:

```
[A ,B, C,D,E]
[A, C, G, B, E]
[A,Z,B,D,E]
...
[A,B,R,D,E]
```

Each with length of  5 items that start with A.

I would like to construct a tree or directed acyclic graph (while with counts a weights ) where each level is the index of the item i.e A have edges with all possible items in the first index, they will have edge with child  in the second index and so on.

is there an easy way to build in in networkx ? what i thought to do is to create all the tuples for each level i.e for level 0 : (A,B) ,(A,C) , (A,Z) etc ..  but not sure how to move with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you can set each list as a path using [`nx.add_path`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9/reference/generated/networkx.Graph.add_path.html) of a directed graph.

```
l = [['A' ,'B', 'C','D','E'],
     ['A', 'C','G', 'B', 'E'],
     ['A','Z','B','D','E'],
     ['A','B','R','D','E']]
```

Though since you have nodes across multiple levels, you should probably rename them according to their level, since you cannot have multiple nodes with the same name. So one way could be:

```
l = [[f'{j}_level{lev}' for lev,j in enumerate(i, 1)] for i in l]
#[['A_level1', 'B_level2', 'C_level3', 'D_level4', 'E_level5'],
# ['A_level1', 'C_level2', 'G_level3', 'B_level4', 'E_level5'],
# ['A_level1', 'Z_level2', 'B_level3', 'D_level4', 'E_level5'],
# ['A_level1', 'B_level2', 'R_level3', 'D_level4', 'E_level5']]
```

And now construct the graph with:   ​

```
G = nx.DiGraph()
for path in l:
    nx.add_path(G, path)
```

Then you could create a tree-like structure using a graphviz's dot layout:

```
from networkx.drawing.nx_agraph import graphviz_layout
pos=graphviz_layout(G, prog='dot')
nx.draw(G, pos=pos,
        node_color='lightgreen', 
        node_size=1500,
        with_labels=True, 
        arrows=True)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks. i would like it to be a tree form , i.e the Root is A , the child is all the items that are in the index 1 of each list, the corresponding childs will be all items in index 2 of the list and so on. edges should be only between items from the level (i) and the childs in level (i+1)

Comment: Yes, but how are you going to get a proper tree like structure with these paths? Take `B` for instance. Its on index 1, index 2 *and* index 3 @latent

Comment: i dont mind having having them on several levels as long as they are not connected to each other. A,B,C are ID of questions and i want to follow sequences of questions

Comment: You see the problem is that you cannot have a graph with multiple nodes sharing the same name @latent So you'd probably have to modify their name, or add a suffix

Comment: See if this resembles what you want @latent (updated)